# Cual es la razón por la que código de C con punteros que funciona sin problemas en linux tiene problemas en MAC?

Tags: c, punteros

En el siguiente ejemplo se muestra una implementación de arrays dinámicos en C usando *malloc* y *realloc*. Cuando este código es compilado en Linux (C11) no hay ningún problema funciona, pero si el mismo código se ejecuta en un MAC (Xcode en un macbook Sierra para ser más exactos) empiezan los problemas, el programa compila pero al ejecutarse aparece un error en la línea que hace el realloc indicando que no se tiene permiso para acceder a esta posición de memoria.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define TRUE 1;
    #define FALSE 0;


    struct dynarray {
        int * data;
        int capacity;
        int size;
    };

    struct dynarray array1;


    int daInit(struct dynarray * dynArrayPtr,int capacity){
        int * arrayDataAddress = (int *)malloc(capacity * sizeof(int));
        if (arrayDataAddress != NULL){
            dynArrayPtr->data = arrayDataAddress;
            dynArrayPtr->capacity = capacity;
            dynArrayPtr->size = 0;
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    int daPushBack(struct dynarray * dynArrayPtr, int value){
        if (dynArrayPtr->size == dynArrayPtr->capacity){
            dynArrayPtr->capacity *= 2;
            dynArrayPtr->data = (int *)realloc(dynArrayPtr->data,dynArrayPtr->capacity * sizeof(int)); 
            if (dynArrayPtr->data == NULL){
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        *(dynArrayPtr->data + dynArrayPtr->size * sizeof(int)) = value;
        dynArrayPtr->size++;
        return TRUE;
    }


    int daIntGet(struct dynarray * dynArrayPtr, int position){
        int* elementPos = (int *) dynArrayPtr->data + sizeof(int) * position;
        return *elementPos;
    }



    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        daInit(&array1,5);
        printf("%p\n", array1.data);
        for (int i=0; i<10;i++){
            if (!daPushBack(&array1,i)) exit(0);
        }

        for (int i=0; i<array1.size; i++){
            printf("%i\n", daIntGet(&array1,i));
        }

        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No sé porque funciona en tu sistema Linux. Debe ser mala suerte (digo mala porque escondió el defecto).

En C, la aritmética con punteros toma en cuenta el tamaño del objeto apuntado. Es decir, dado que `dynArrayPtr->data` apunta a un `int`, la computación `dynArrayPtr->data + i` apunta al elemento `i` con desplazamiento `i * sizeof(int)` bytes. En consecuencia,

```
*(dynArrayPtr->data + dynArrayPtr->size * sizeof(int)) = value;
```

puede modificar a memoria fuera de la memoria alocada. La expresión `data + size` apunta al byte `data + size*sizeof(size)`, así case `data + size*sizeof(size)` apunta a `data + size*sizeof(size)*sizeof(size)`. Utilizas la misma expresión equivocada en `daIntGet`, así que lees la misma ubicación que escribiste, pero es memoria ajena, que puede ser ocupada por otra estructura o puede ser no presente en el mapa de memoria (por lo cual recibes un segfault en el Mac).

En fin, deberías poner

```
*(dynArrayPtr->data + dynArrayPtr->size) = value;
```

pero de mi juicio, más claro sea

```
dynArrayPtr->data[dynArrayPtr->size] = value;
```

que tiene exactamente la misma semántica.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Casi seguro que funciona en Linux por la distinta implementación de `realloc( )` y la *granularidad* mínima de los bloques de memória reservados, lo que lo hará fallar dependiendo del tamaño del array. Un tema, la aritmética de punteros, *duro* para los que se inician.